# define static routes at boot

Tags: boot, networking, server, 10.04, gateway

I'm running Ubuntu desktop 10.04 and on every boot the machine cannot be accessed from outside the LAN. after running `sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1` everything works as expected. Is there any way to make this happen on boot? I've tried adding a cron job but that didn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the above command  to /etc/rc.local

```
 route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

You need to remove sudo part since /etc/rc.local running as root.
Anything added to this file will be executed after all other startup programs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and report back. It may be a while since I'm away from the server and, because of this problem, am reluctant to restart it remotely.